# Is there a way in Meteor to check if a 500 error is thrown from the server side?

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, iron-router

I would like to redirect user to a custom 500 error page whenever I see server throws a 500 internal server error.

Like if I am calling this method:

```
throwError: function () {
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Custom 500 Internal Server Error");
}
```

I am expecting some method is watching any server error being thrown and do a check for 500 and then redirect.

I can see when I am calling this method my console is telling me a 500 error is thrown.

```
Error invoking Method 'throwError': Custom 500 Internal Server Error [500]
```

from debug.js line 41.

But how can watch this error and do something myself?

I am not talking about watching that method specifically but as soon as server error is thrown.